# Main menu with real loading screen and different game modes

Tags: unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

I would like to have a Main Menu, from which the Player can select a Level and be presented with a loading screen until that Level is ready.

I have tried to implement this with a Persistent Level which utilizes Level Streaming. It first loads the Main Menu Level. When the player selects another Level from the Main Menu, a function is called in the Persistent Level to display a loading screen until Level Streaming completes for the Level they selected. However, if you can’t change GameMode based on level streaming, how can it stream other Levels with different rules (e.g. Deathmatch, Capture the Flag) if the GameMode has to stay the same?

I can find tutorials on creating a menu and opening other levels, but if you want to use a 'real' loading screen (not just a widget that appears for X seconds), how can you achieve this? The loading screen tutorials I found use Level Streaming but I don't know how to get this to work with different GameModes.

Comment: You could look into the source code of the [Lyra sample game](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/lyra-sample-game-in-unreal-engine/) for a good loading screen solution. This, however, is (as far as I know) not 100% blueprint ready.

Answer (score 0):

Note: this is Unreal 5 specific, earlier versions have a different implementation. I base the version on the tag in your question.

If you need a different game mode, you need to switch the persistent level with [OpenLevel](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.1/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Kismet/UGameplayStatics/OpenLevel/). However, a `UWidget` that was added to the screen is added per-level, so it is removed from the screen when that happens. That is because the `OnLevelRemovedFromWorld()` of `UGameViewportSubsystem` removes them:

> If the InLevel is null, it's a signal that the entire world is about to disappear, so go ahead and remove this widget from the viewport, it could be holding onto too many dangerous actor references that won't carry over into the next world. -- comment of `UGameViewportSubsystem::OnLevelRemovedFromWorld`

So, to make sure a loading widget is added to the screen when the level transition happens, you need do listen to the level transition happening in `FWorldDelegates`. You can use `LevelRemovedFromWorld` for the transition starting, and `LevelAddedToWorld` for it ending, for example.

```cpp
// in your game instance
// .h
void OnLevelRemovedFromWorld(ULevel* InLevel, UWorld* InWorld);
void OnLevelAddedToWorld(ULevel* InLevel, UWorld* InWorld);


// .cpp
// in function when starting transition (idk where you do this), start listening:
FWorldDelegates::LevelRemovedFromWorld.AddUObject(this, &ThisClass::OnLevelRemovedFromWorld);
FWorldDelegates::LevelAddedToWorld.AddUObject(this, &ThisClass::OnLevelAddedToWorld);

// also implement the functions to add your loading widget
void UYourGameInstance::OnLevelRemovedFromWorld(ULevel* InLevel, UWorld* InWorld) {
    if (InLevel == nullptr) {
        // this will be true when transition starts
        // stop listening
        FWorldDelegates::LevelRemovedFromWorld.RemoveUObject(this, &ThisClass::OnLevelRemovedFromWorld);
        // add your loading widget -- you can write this with your specific classes yourself I assume
        YourWidget->AddToViewport(0);
}
void UYourGameInstance::OnLevelAddedToWorld(ULevel* InLevel, UWorld* InWorld){
    // we no longer need to listen to this
    FWorldDelegates::LevelAddedToWorld.RemoveUObject(this, &ThisClass::OnLevelAddedToWorld);
    // remove the loading widget
    UGameViewportSubsystem::Get(InWorld)->RemoveWidget(YourWidget);
}
```

You can explore FWorldDelegates for other types of delegates, maybe some will be more fitting.

I don't exactly the names of the classes you have, but this can be a starting point. If anything isn't clear, let me know in a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - is this possible with blueprints?

Comment: I don't think so unfortunately, as removing the widgets of the world when one gets unloaded is quite a architecture-level feature of the engine that BP is not meant to access. However, the interoparbility of C++ and BP is very flexible, if you project is mainly BP, it's possible to add functionality in C++ for only specific things that require it, and keep everything else in BP.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of searching for an answer to this, I found that there is no easy way to do this via Blueprints. However, I have been able to implement a main menu, multiplayer lobby and loading screens using a combination of Seamless Travel and Level Streaming.
[image]
When a host starts the game from the lobby (MenuGameMode), they initiate a ‘servertravel’ (Seamless Travel) which migrates all players to the PersistentCampaignMap (CampaignGameMode) while keeping them connected to the session. An issue with this approach is that the Transition Level appears briefly between the client seeing the lobby and seeing the loading screen.

PersistentCampaignMap serves only as a persistent level to stream the playable maps. From it’s Level Blueprint, the server calls an RPC on each client to display a loading screen and then initiates Level Streaming of the chosen campaign map (e.g. Campaign1Map). Once the Level Streaming is complete, the server calls a function in CampaignGameMode to reset the players at their starting positions, hide the loading screens and start the game.